# android back button closing an app

Tags: android

my simple app is just loading a website, on website are some topics so I want if somebody click back button to return to index(to last webpage),
I have this code in MainActivity.java

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        moveTaskToBack(true);
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}      
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    moveTaskToBack(true);
}
```

After pushing back button it is closing my app, where can be problem?

Comment: Loading the website in a webview or in a browser?

Comment: it is loading in a webview

Comment: Here is an example code that does that http://www.technotalkative.com/android-webviewclient-example/

Comment: thanks for the link, working perfectly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should return true when the webView consumed the back event in your `onKeyDown` method.

```
   @Override
   public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
  {
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && web.canGoBack()) {
        web.goBack();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
   }
```

In your code you let the back event be propagated to the main Activity, meaning that it will finish.

Source: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onKeyDown(int, android.view.KeyEvent)

> **Returns** If you handled the event, return true. If you want to allow the event to be handled by the next receiver, return false.

Answer (score 1):

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && web.canGoBack()) {
        web.goBack();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```